# Node.js+npm, should I use global or local module install?

Tags: node.js

When and why should I install node modules globally and locally? Why many manuals have "npm install -g" while other do not? Is this project or OS specific?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taken from an official [node.js blog](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/):

> In general, the rule of thumb is:
>
> 1) If you’re installing something that you want to use in your
>   program, using require('whatever'), then install it locally, at the
>   root of your project.
>
> 2) If you’re installing something that you want to use in your shell,
>   on the command line or something, install it globally, so that its
>   binaries end up in your PATH environment variable.